# Install node in ec2 with Amazon Linux2 error glibc >= 2.28

Tags: node.js, linux, npm, centos

Trying to install npm and node on:

```
cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Amazon Linux"
VERSION="2"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="centos rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux 2"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:2.3:o:amazon:amazon_linux:2"
HOME_URL="https://amazonlinux.com/"
SUPPORT_END="2025-06-30"
```

And no matter I use : `curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_xxx.x | sudo -E bash -` or nvm option, I get:

```
    Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package nodejs.x86_64 2:18.19.0-1nodesource will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: glibc >= 2.28 for package: 2:nodejs-18.19.0-1nodesource.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libm.so.6(GLIBC_2.27)(64bit) for package: 2:nodejs-18.19.0-1nodesource.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.28)(64bit) for package: 2:nodejs-18.19.0-1nodesource.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: 2:nodejs-18.19.0-1nodesource.x86_64 (nodesource-nodejs)
           Requires: libm.so.6(GLIBC_2.27)(64bit)
Error: Package: 2:nodejs-18.19.0-1nodesource.x86_64 (nodesource-nodejs)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.28)(64bit)
Error: Package: 2:nodejs-18.19.0-1nodesource.x86_64 (nodesource-nodejs)
           Requires: glibc >= 2.28
           Installed: glibc-2.26-63.amzn2.0.1.x86_64 (@amzn2-core)
               glibc = 2.26-63.amzn2.0.1
```

There's no way to run some decent version (ideally LTS) on this machine? It's not such an old machine, would starting a new ec2 have a more up to date OS/ gcc-c++ that would allow me to have some useful node setup?

Comment: Use amazon linux 2023